# breaking down triple congurence relationships

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do you read the statement,i.e. what does this mean? example is a congruent to b? there's no mod for b, does this mean they are equal?:

$$a \equiv b \equiv H mod M$$
And, if we were to break this statement to two simpler statements of congruence, how do we do that?

Comment: Just imagine equalities $a=b=H$ in the quotient $\Bbb Z/M\Bbb Z$. So we read this as usual: $a=H$ and $b=H$ and $a=b$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde , but in congruence, there no $a\equiv b$ without defining a mod world, and congruence and equals are different

Comment: Not true! $a\equiv b \bmod m$ is by definition equivalent to the equation $a=b$ in the ring $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde , Haven't studied rings, but what does $a\equiv b$ mean then? but $a \equiv b mod n$ means $n|a-b$

Comment: @DietrichBurde , in my statement above, is the mod M relavant for all, can we break it down like $a mod m = b mod m = H mod m$ ?

Answer (score 0):

$a \equiv b \equiv H mod M$ can basically be written as: 
$$a \equiv b mod M $$
$$a \equiv H mod M $$
$$b \equiv H mod M $$